# Prepare for Segue in Swift with Sender

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uistoryboardsegue, sender

I am trying to pass a `UIColor` to another viewController via a "show" segue so that the color of the background can match that of the color button that was selected. I have this bit of code that prints the buttons sender tag but it is not performing that segue.

What am I doing wrong? I have never worked with sender tags before so it could be something silly but I am not sure.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toQuiz" {
            if sender?.tag == 1 {

                let viewController:ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
                let color = UIColor.blueColor()
                viewController.passedColor = color

            } else if sender!.tag == 2 {

                let viewController:ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
                let color = UIColor.greenColor()
                viewController.passedColor = color

            } else if sender!.tag == 3 {

                let viewController:ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
                let color = UIColor.yellowColor()
                viewController.passedColor = color

            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func athButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let athleteQuiz = sender as! UIButton
        print("Button \(athleteQuiz.tag) was pressed!")
    }

    @IBAction func actorButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let actorQuiz = sender as! UIButton
        print("Button \(actorQuiz.tag) was pressed!")
    }

    @IBAction func musicButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let musicQuiz = sender as! UIButton
        print("Button \(musicQuiz.tag) was pressed!")
    }
```

This is the storyboard layout - they are all connected properly and the identifier for the segue matches that in the storyboard.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are your segue properly connected in storyboard  ? also check the identifier

Comment: Hi Shubhank, I just added some pictures to further assist anybody that is kind enough to help me out!

Comment: Is the prepareForSegue being called at all? If not, check your storyboard and make sure that the left view controller has the proper class assigned to it. If you made direct segues from the buttons in Interface Builder, the transition would still happen, but your class methods wouldn't be called because your class isn't being instantiated.

Comment: is the segue attached to the button ? or some other view ?

Comment: You should change the colors in viewDidLoad(). In prepareForSegue() the views aren't ready, yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Does the left view controller have your class assigned to it in IB?
- Is anything actually triggering the segue? Neither of your button actions contain a call to `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:sender:)`

Also, this is a very dangerous block of code; you should not be force-unwrapping sender like that. Instead, consider doing something like this:

```
guard let id = segue.identifier else { return } // Bail if there isn't a segue ID.
if id == "toQuiz" {
    guard let tag = (sender as? UIView)?.tag else { return } // Bail if we can't get a tag.

    // Continue examining the tag.
}
```